# How I can stop start up banner in Visual Studio Code 1.56.0?

Tags: visual-studio-code

```json
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-nologo"],
```

This thing isn't working in the current version.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: I assume you mean VS Code?

Comment: "VS Studio 1.56.0"? You probably mean "Visual Studio Code 1.56.0".

Comment: Why is this tagged [tag:c++]?

Comment: @molbdnilo you're right .

Comment: Did you search the VSC GitHub if they know it as a current issue, if they don't maybe make it as a new issue? https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues But if it's a real bug without workarounds then probably just downgrade/upgrade will work.